# Superscript wedge on an $R$-module

Tags: notation, modules, tensor-products

I'm reading these lecture notes [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) about the tensor product and the author uses $M^\vee$ where $M$ is an $R$-module. Look at page 2 for an example (example 2.1). What does it mean? I looked through the notes but I couldn't find the definition. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I do not see where this notation is used on page 8.

Comment: @Qiaochu: sorry, that was a typo, it should've said page 3!

Comment: It should've said page 2, not page 3. The file has been updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M^{\vee}$ (which in $\LaTeX$ is not a \wedge) is the dual $R$-module; that is, it's the $R$-module of all $R$-module homomorphisms $M \to R$, or more concisely it's $\text{Hom}_R(M, R)$. This is why the author refers to the dual pairing on page 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know what to search for because I didn't know it was called 'dual'.

Comment: Is this a standard notation?  I think i have encountered $M^*$ more often.